# Visually get the id of an object in a PDF

Tags: pdf, edit

I want to get the id of an object (some text)) in a PDF file for a one off processing task. Can I do this with a GUI that lets me click on an object and get it's ID?

I'm sort of assuming that all objects in a pdf have a unique ID.

Comment: And what do you expect that id to be? There are indirect objects with an object number, but the whole content stream of a page may be contained in a single indirect object...

Comment: Well... I want to see what happens when I delete it!

Comment: @KJ that's a littlle depressing. Is it the kind of think I could hack up in python, or am I going to end up implementing a quarter of a PDF editor when trying to do this.